# Trying to format current month

Tags: vba, excel

I have looked at multiple forums can cannot find a solution to my problem.
I am trying to get the current month of today's date.
If I use 
msgbox month(date) 
I get the value 1 for January
but if I format it using 
msgbox format(month(date), "mmmm") 
it returns December.
Does anyone know why or where my mistake it? 
I am trying to avoid writing lengthy code like if 1 then "January, else if 2 then "February", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
Sub WhatsInaName()
    MsgBox Format(Date, "mmmm")
End Sub
```

[image]

As to why you were getting December:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim d As Date
    d = CDate(1)
    MsgBox d
End Sub
```

yields:

[image]

Comment: wow, I cannot believe I missed that. Thank you Gary's Student , I guess I have been staring at code too long today and should just walk away to clear my head for a little bit.